# delete from end of lines using block select in vim

Tags: vim

I'm getting an unusual behavior when I try to delete from end of lines using block selection in vim.

So let's say I have a text as such:

```
delete this char:x
and this:x
also this:x
and then this:x
lastly this:x
```

If I want to append `y` to every line I can:

- start block selection with <kbd>C-v</kbd>
- select all the lines with `4j`
- go to ends of lines with `$`
- start appending with `A`
- type the desired text `y`

in order to get:

```
delete this char:xy
and this:xy
also this:xy
and then this:xy
lastly this:xy
```

but if I try to delete `x` in the last step instead of appending I would expect to get:

```
delete this char:
and this:
also this:
and then this:
lastly this:
```

although I end up with:

```
delete this char:
and this:x:
also this:x:
and then this:x:
lastly this:x:
```

As far as I understand it appends the last char in the first line to all other lines (in this case `:`) rather than deleting the missing ones (in this case `x`).

I can do this with macros or substitutes but I don't quite understand the rationale behind such behavior. Is there a way I can do this with block selection?

Comment: I don't get the behaviour you describe. The first `x` is removed but nothing is added.

Comment: @romainl are you using the same examples from the question? if you're using something like `delete this char: x` and delete `x`, it adds trailing spaces which may be easy to miss..

Comment: Nope, I can see trailing spaces fine and there are none. In this context, `<C-v>{movement}$A`, removing characters is not done on every line in the selection anyway. Only adding characters works. It's a bit shortsighted, if you want my opinion, but that's how it is designed. Removing `x` at the end of a range of lines is typically done with `:'<,'>norm $x` or `:'<,'>s/x$//`.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried `:{range}normal`?  This should work:

```
:'<,'>normal $x
```

(The `'<,'>` bit is filled in for you when you type <kbd>:</kbd>.)

Comment: I think an explanation what it does to the above solution would be great. I tried to edit one in but it was rejected.

Comment: `{range}` is pretty common Vim vernacular in the help files. `normal` is a command that enters the following things like you were typing them in normal mode. So altogether, this command does for-each-line: go to end of line then delete the character under the cursor.

Comment: Note: you need to use `ctrl+V` to select a visual block first.

Answer (score 6):

`$` `C-v` `4j` `x`

1. go to end of line with `$`
2. toggle visual block `C-v`
3. go down (in your case 4x) `4j`
4. delete that stuff with `x`

**Edit**: (reacting on your comment for arbitrary indentation)

That can be done with simple macro. Macros are not so hard as you can think:

1. start recording a macro, we will name it 'a', so `qa`
2. go to the end of line `$`
3. delete one character `x`
4. go down by one line with `j`
5. end our macro `q`

Now apply our macro: `20@a` - will do the same you did while you was recording the macro, 20x.

Comment: This works but I need something that would work with arbitrary indentation. I have edited the question accordingly..

Comment: The problem with the macro solution is that I have to count the lines I need to modify.

Answer (score 6):

If I have a small number of lines I typically do <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>. Then repeatedly do <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> until done. Not the fastest way but easy to remember.

For a large amount of lines I typically visually select the lines via <kbd>V</kbd> then do a substitution or a normal command on the range.

```
:'<,'>s/.$//
:'<,'>norm $x
```

Note: you do not have to type `'<,'>`. It will be inserted automatically when you start a command when some text is visually selected.

The substitution command is pretty simple, match the last character (`.$`) and then replace it with nothing.

The normal command is just how you would delete the last character in normal mode via <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> for a single line except it will apply it to each line in the range.

For more help see:

```
:h range
:h :s
:h :norm
```

Comment: If you make it a macro you can repeat it an arbitrary number of times, eg. `10@<register>` rather than `j.j.j.j.j.j.j.j.j.j.` (4 keystrokes instead of twenty, plus the 3 extra necessary to record a macro (`q<register>` ... `q`)).

Answer (score 2):

as you said yourself, to achieve your goal, there are other ways, in fact better ways to go. `:s` or `q(macro)` or `:g/.../norm $x`. `:s/.$//g` is pretty straightforward.

Ctrl-V is not suitable for this job. As for its name: Visual **BLOCK**. You want to remove the last x, and they (only x) are not in a block.

However if you really want to stick with ctrl-v, you have to do some extra work, to make those 'x' in a block. If you have Align plugin installed, you could :

Select (`V`) all lines you want to do the trick,

```
<leader>t:
```

then your text looks like:

```
delete this char : x
and this         : x
also this        : x
and then this    : x
lastly this      : x
```

`Ctrl-V` to remove x, you should know how to do it.

then

```
:%s/ *:/:/g
```

to remove padded spaces before ':'

However I don't think it is a good way to go.

Comment: These are all good and all but none of these are as intuitive as visual blocks to me. I want to leave the question open for a while before giving up because I still feel like there's no reason to prevent implementing such a feature.